# Why does adding a filetype to PATHEXT cause invocations to say "Access is denied"?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, environment-variables

My goal: to run a file `hello.py` on my %PATH% when I write `hello`.

What I've done:

- Made sure `.py` is part of `PATHEXT`.

```
C:\Windows\System32>echo %PATHEXT%
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYZ;.PYW
```

- Made sure `.py` is associated with the ftype `Python.File` and that `Python.File` is associated with my Python installation.

```
C:\Windows\System32>ftype | findstr -i python
Python.File="C:/Users/gal/scoop/apps/python311/current/python.exe" "%1" %*

C:\Windows\System32>assoc .py
.py=Python.File
```

- Made sure `hello.py` is on my %PATH% and that it executes correctly when I manually specify the Python executable, including taking arguments.

```
C:\Windows\System32>where hello
c:\path\hello.py

C:\Windows\System32>C:\Users\gal\scoop\apps\python311\current\python.exe c:\path\hello.py George Elaine
Hello, George and Elaine
```

Based on everything I'm reading this should be enough for it to work, but when I run `hello.py` or `hello` I get "Access is denied".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the file have 'Execute' permission granted? What does `icacls` show about it?

Comment: @u1686_grawity icacls shows that it  BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F), NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F), BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX), NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M).